# Finding out the difference between time between 2 times with speed>=0 and speed<=5

Tags: python

Please refer to the attached image for reference, really hope someone can help me with this. Essentially I have a dataframe c, with columns 'timestamp' and 'speed'. What I am trying to do is to find the timeframe in which the speed is less than or equal to 5 and more than or equal to 0. For example, for index 1, we have speed = 0 and the timestamp is 06:00:28. The speed remains at between 0 and 5 up till index 7 (timestamp: 06:01:27, speed :2) because at index 8, the speed is 7. What I want to do is find the difference in times between 06:01:27 and 06:00:28.

Following this, at index 9, a series of data points with 0<=speed<=5 appears again with index 9 (timestamp:06:01:44, speed:1) and this continues until index 14 (timestamp:06:05:20,speed:2). I would like to find again the difference between 06:05:20 and 06:01:44.

I have indicated the relevant portions with highlights for reference.

All help is appreciated!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLCDj.png

Comment: Can you please put this data in programable form as well as expected results?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.